# Code stops executing after first time, without error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm doing a small app in Excel, and I have the following code when the user clicks a Button in a UserForm

```
Private Sub SubmitNuevo_Click()
    Call FindNextEmptyRow 'after this nextEmptyCell has a Range object
    Dim currCell As Range
    Set currCell = nextEmptyCell.Cells(1, 1)
    Dim s() As String
    s = Split("macro,name,area,dept,model,range,prior,found", ",")
    currCell.Value = Date
    For i = 0 To UBound(s)
        currCell.Offset(0, dict.Item(s(i)) - 1).Value = Me.Controls(s(i) & "Nuevo").Text
    Next
End Sub
```

When I just opened the Workbook and run this, it works fine, filling up a row of the Sheet with values from TextBoxes, but if I try to run it more times, it executes `currCell.Value = Date` and then just stops executing without an error or anything. If I re-open the workbook it works fine the first time I try to run it, but then fails every other try.

Any ideas what might be happening here?

Comment: How do you know it stops executing after `currCell.Value = Date`?  Have you set breakpoints and stepped through the code?  Or are you just not seeing the effects of the following lines of code?

Comment: If you step through the code, line-by-line, what happens after `currCell.Value = Date` the 2nd time you run it?

Comment: Yea I did set a breakpoint. That cell's value changes to the Date, as it's supposed to do, and the the program just stops, and the Form closes without an error.

Comment: not sure this will solve it, but try placing `i=0` between `currCell.Value = Date` and `For i = 0 To UBound(s)`

Comment: So, when you step through the code line-by-line, what happens when you get to the line `For i = 0 To UBound(s)`? Does it begin the loop execution after you hit F8 on it?

Comment: No, the code never gets to the For loop. Something at the .Value is probably causing the error. I just noticed the same problem happens in other procedures of my app that are essentially doing the same.

Comment: check your other code, perhaps there's a Worksheet_Change Event or something. If you can post a link to your workbook (without sensitive data), we can take a look.

Comment: Here's a link to the Workbook https://www.dropbox.com/s/viq2604hka8xufu/User2.xlsm

Comment: Sorry, my work creds are tight. I can't get at files on dropbox. SOmeone else will have to chime in. Best to you.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error on my computer. If I fill in values in the text fields and hit submit multiple times, it keeps adding lines to the worksheet with no issues.

Comment: The error happens when you run the form, do it a couple times, close the form (leaving the Workbook open), re-run the form, and now the error happens.

Comment: I might have solved it with ActiveWorkbook.Save after the For loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving the Workbook after each click of the button appears to solve the issue. Just added

```
ActiveWorkbook.Save
```

before the `End Sub`.